# Consider split words to be correct words

Tags: hunspell

Let's assume I have 2 words in dic file

```
this
that
```

If I type a word "thisthat" it will suggest "this that" because by default split suggestion option is enabled.
If I disable that option then hunspell will suggest some other word.

I have understood this part.

The question is what if I want hunspell to consider both, "thisthat" and ""thatthis" to be correct words?
Is this possible?

---

Update:

As per documentation this is what I am looking for.

```
              # affix file
              COMPOUNDFLAG X

              2
              foo/X
              bar/X

       With this resource, foobar and barfoo also are accepted words.
```

Can I add the  /X part to all words?
How many combinations will it generate if there are  thousands of words in dic file?

---

Update 2

I need "foobared" word and therefore I added this to affix file...

```
SFX b Y 1
SFX b 0 ed/X .
```

and updated the dic file

```
bar/Xb
```

with this change, I got "bared" but not "foobared".

Any suggestion will be appreciated. I need "foobared" word to be considered correct when I have only 2 words "foo" and "bar" in dict. And no, you can not use "foo" as affix tag! You can use CHECKCOMPOUNDPATTERN tag if required.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, you can add the COMPOUNDFLAG to every word.

However, you do not want to, per the concern you seem to already be expressing, that it will generate enormous numbers of possible combinations.  For only two words, ~(# words)^2

The docs themselves note that "Allowing free compounding yields a decrease in precision of recognition, not to mention stemming and morphological analysis."

I recommend looking at the far more complex examples further down in the compounding documentation when they start dealing with Hungarian and German word issues, and the Options for Compounding.

[Hunspell Docs - Compounding](https://www.mankier.com/5/hunspell#Compounds)

[Hunspell Docs - Options for Compounding](https://www.mankier.com/5/hunspell#Options_for_Compounding)

Note, just for the example with only a couple words, they use:

COMPOUNDBEGIN, COMPOUNDMIDDLE, COMPOUNDEND, COMPOUNDPERMITFLAG, ONLYINCOMPOUND, COMPOUNDMIN, and FORBIDDENWORD.

There are a lot of other options if you want to handle complex cases or limit compounding to only a subset of the possible choices.